# Run-Time Error '6' overflow (copy range from closed workbook)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the below code placed on my active workbook which copy's data from a closed workbook. It works fine and very fast but i can only copy up to 8 columns if I select more than that I get a

> run-time error 6 - Overflow

**Code**:

```
Sub Get_Data()

Dim RngToCopy As Range
Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim DestCell As Range
Dim myFileNames As Variant
Dim iCtr As Long
Dim testStr As String

Set DestCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1")

myFileNames = Array("C:\my documents\excel\book1.xlsm") ' i could add more workbooks to copy from and append on current worksheet

For iCtr = LBound(myFileNames) To UBound(myFileNames)
    testStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    testStr = Dir(myFileNames(iCtr))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If testStr = "" Then
        MsgBox myFileNames(iCtr) & " doesn't exist!"
    Else
        Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFileNames(iCtr))
        With wkbk.Worksheets(1)
            Set RngToCopy = .Range("a2:r2", _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With

        DestCell.Resize(RngToCopy.Rows.Count, _
            RngToCopy.Columns.Count).Value _
            = RngToCopy.Value

        Set DestCell = DestCell.Offset(RngToCopy.Rows.Count, 0)
        wkbk.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
Next iCtr

End Sub
```

when I debug the line that it goes to is: where am I going wrong :(

```
DestCell.Resize(RngToCopy.Rows.Count, _
RngToCopy.Columns.Count).Value _
= RngToCopy.Value
```

the source workbook is a big file with a lot of data, I tried most of the suggestions when I researched on the error but no luck.

if it helps workbook contains 18 columns and 300k+ rows

Comment: I believe it has to do with how you are selecting the RngToCopy. You want to select the range by selecting individual cells to specify the contiguous range you are interested in. Something like this : `Dim rngToCopy As Range: Set rngToCopy = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(15, lastrow))`

Comment: i tried that but gave me run time error 91 'object variable or with block variable not set' ? @RyanWildry

Comment: i think that your problem is that: the destination book you use is xls which contains 65536 rows, but you say to your question that has 300k rows..please change the destination workbook to xlsm –

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis sorry the source workbook is actually .xlsm i have edited the question

Comment: Does it help if you Copy/Paste rather than using `Value = Value`?

Comment: @Mohammed did you remember to include `Set`?

Comment: @Mohammed your destination workbook is xlsm too?

Comment: the point which debug the line goes shows as that the RngToCopy overflows, thats why i ask you for the type of destination workbook

Comment: thank you guys for your suggestion , i have found an answer from @ShaiRado his approach worked perfect for my needs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different approach, use **Copy >> PasteSpecial** (values only) :

```
' 1st: set copy range
With wkbk.Worksheets(1)
    Set RngToCopy = .Range("A2:R2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

' 2nd: set destination range start position
Set DestCell = DestCell.Offset(RngToCopy.Rows.Count, 0)

' 3rd: use copy>>paste special (values only)
RngToCopy.Copy
DestCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```